# How to prove that $c=(Id-B)A^{-1}b \hspace{1cm} $ if $x^{k+1}=Bx^{k}+c$ converges to the solution of $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, gradient-descent

Prove that  if $x^{k+1}=Bx^{k}+c$, converge to the solution of $Ax=b$ then $c=(Id-B)A^{-1}b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking limit on $x_{n+1}=Bx_n+c$ as $n\to \infty$
$$x=Bx+c\Rightarrow c=(I-B)x=(I-B)A^{-1}b.$$

Comment: Where is the $d$ of $(Id-B)A^{-1}b$?

Comment: There's no $d$, like $d=1$. Anything in the solution unclear? Maybe it has a mistake somewhere? Thanks.